# how to determine problems with page load

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, page-speed

Im hosting a website in a shared hosting environment. i think im pretty decent coder. I have done every possible way to improve my page performance including caching and gzipping the content. Still my users are facing problem.

My site url is http://thinkmovie.in

First of all im not sure if the page load time is normal for my website. If it is high, i want to know the exact reason. Im thinking the server is the bottleneck here. How can anyone know that server is causing high page load times.

I have just implemented [boomerang](http://yahoo.github.com/boomerang/doc/howtos/howto-0.html)
but no sure how to use it to full capacity. I'm also scared that logging its details into database will further slow down the site.Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[According to GTMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/thinkmovie.in/jlYtseOD) your site could use some improvements, but generally is not bad.

Your page makes 111 requests, totaling over 700 KB. While that's not abysmal, I'd suggest reducing that if possible. Could you remove one column of images from the block on the right, and limit the tab box at the bottom to one row?

Comment: http://gtmetrix.com/compare/jlYtseOD/u5vWqkbs. can u tell me the reason for this